# Method post works on localhost but not in web server

Tags: php, html, webserver

1.- Im having a problem uploading files to the web server, the thing is that I dont think the code has problem, because when I test it on the localhost, it works fine, but not on the web-server. Anyway I leave you guys the code, the form-submit and the file that handles the request, I mean is just a thing to upload a file, is very easy, I dont want to waste your time, because I know its easy, but is so obvious to me that I dont find answers, the only thing I think would be a problem is on the webserver, Im being  reading online that could be the php.ini configuration (Im not sure about this).
Form:


    `<form action="subir.php" id="form10" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <td width="80%">
    <input id="archivoxsl" name="archivoxsl" type="file" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input id="enviar1" name="enviar1" type="submit" value="" class="guardar" />
    </td>
    </form>`
Code to upload files
`if(isset($_POST))
    {
    echo "ok";
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['archivoxsl']['name']);
    echo '<pre>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivoxsl']['tmp_name'],  $_FILES['archivoxsl']['name']))
    {echo "done";
    }
    else
    {
    echo $_FILES['archivoxsl']['name'];
    }
    echo "Nombre de archivo: ".$_FILES['archivoxsl']['tmp_name'];
    echo 'Aquí hay más información de depurado:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I thinking your problem is the file size. By default PHP max_upload_size is 2M, if you upload more than 2M, your server prevent this, $_FILES will be empty.

Comment: ok, I tried to upload files less than 1M, and the problem still there, anyway the configuration you said is in the web server ?, I mean the problem is tahat I only have the backend files, (A ftp storage that only keeps files of the developpment system) if you are right then I need to contact the administrator of the webserver, isn´t it ?

Comment: Depending server you can set it with:  php command ini_set(), or php_value inside .htaccess file or set it by default on php.ini file. Try first ini_set and .htaccess. You can do phpinfo() later to show if variable is modificated.  The variables you need to modify are post_max_size and upload_max_filesize, the value, for example 20M